# List top 10 gold badge medalists in Code Review

Tags: data.stackexchange.com

What I want to achieve in particular is getting top 10 gold badge medalists in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

(A Data Explorer solution is acceptable, too.)

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: 1. You need to fetch a list of all the users and their badges & do the sorting. The Data Explorer is much more convenient for that. 2. What language are you looking to implement your idea in?

Comment: @double-beep Java. Javascript will do as well.

Comment: @double-beep Actually, Data Explorer will do nicely.

Comment: Have you found the solution or are you asking for one? [There's already a query here](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/397276/ten-users-with-most-gold-badges-fixed-to-use-official-list-of-string-gold-badge) ([or here](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/1706897/ten-users-with-most-gold-badges)).

Comment: @double-beep The 2nd link was what I wanted. Thank you, Sir! ^^

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)](https://data.stackexchange.com) what you're asking is *much* easier.

From the `Badges` table, filter only the badges awareded that are gold, group by users and sort by the count.

```sql
SELECT
  TOP 100 UserId AS [User Link],
  COUNT(*)

FROM Badges
WHERE class = 1

GROUP BY UserId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

You can see [the query live here](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/1706897/ten-users-with-most-gold-badges).

---

Reference: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677)